# Classifying observations using Jahmm

Tags: machine-learning, gesture-recognition, hidden-markov-models

I am currently working on a gesture recognition application and I am using HMMs (through Jahmm). Currently I have two gestures (up and down) so I built 2 HMMs, with some training data.

I trained them using the BaumWelchLearner and I created a 'sample' observation sequence obtained from my system which I have to classify.

I think that I managed to complete the above steps from the little support I found. But currently I am stuck at the last stage, I am trying to compute the most likely HMM that fits the current sequence I have, but I am having no helpful outputs (or maybe I cannot understand them). This is my sample code, followed by the output.

```
    //gesture classes
    HmmUp up = new HmmUp();
    HmmDown down = new HmmDown();
    final Hmm<ObservationDiscrete<DirectionVector>> upLearnt;
    final Hmm<ObservationDiscrete<DirectionVector>> downLearnt;

    //train - should read TRAINED HMM OBJECTS in application
    BaumWelchLearner bwl = new BaumWelchLearner();
    bwl.setNbIterations(100);

    upLearnt = bwl.learn(up, up.getTrainingMaterial());
    downLearnt = bwl.learn(down, down.getTrainingMaterial());

    ArrayList<Hmm<ObservationDiscrete<DirectionVector>>> trainedHmms = new ArrayList<Hmm<ObservationDiscrete<DirectionVector>>>(){{
        add(upLearnt);
        add(downLearnt);
    }};

    ArrayList<ObservationDiscrete<DirectionVector>> currentSequence = new ArrayList<ObservationDiscrete<DirectionVector>>(){{
        add(new ObservationDiscrete<DirectionVector>(DirectionVector.NoMovement));
        add(new ObservationDiscrete<DirectionVector>(DirectionVector.Down));
        add(new ObservationDiscrete<DirectionVector>(DirectionVector.Up));
        add(new ObservationDiscrete<DirectionVector>(DirectionVector.Up));
        add(new ObservationDiscrete<DirectionVector>(DirectionVector.Up));
        add(new ObservationDiscrete<DirectionVector>(DirectionVector.Up));
        add(new ObservationDiscrete<DirectionVector>(DirectionVector.Up));
        add(new ObservationDiscrete<DirectionVector>(DirectionVector.UpLeft));
        add(new ObservationDiscrete<DirectionVector>(DirectionVector.Null));
        add(new ObservationDiscrete<DirectionVector>(DirectionVector.Null));
    }};

    //get the observation from the device (continuously feeding - 10 states always with nulls at the end?)
    for (Hmm<ObservationDiscrete<DirectionVector>> hmm : trainedHmms) {

        ViterbiCalculator vc = new ViterbiCalculator(currentSequence, hmm);
        for (int i = 0; i < vc.stateSequence().length; i++)
        {
            System.out.println(vc.stateSequence()[i]);
        }
        System.out.println(vc.lnProbability()); //e to the ln(x) = x

    }
```

This is the current output I am havving, with what seems to be 'empty' state sequences and negative probabilities?!!!

0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
-1.7976931348623157E308

0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
-56.294579216353064

Comment: I'm also just trying to work this library out, but I believe that the HMM that is passed to your Baum-Welch function should already be partially trained? I think their example suggests using K-mean training for this initial step.